# Fast mmaped memory buffer for DMA

Tags: c, memory, dma

I'am currently developing a linux driver for DMA.
The driver allocates a memory region using `dma_alloc_coherent`, which I map to the user space using `_dma_mmap_id = (int*) mmap(NULL, buffer_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, _dma_device_id, 0);`. In the user space, I write and read to this region and trigger DMA transfers.

However, I noticed that writing to the mmaped region is very slow (~100MB/s).
Accordingly, I look for approaches to accelerate this.

I tried to allocate non-coherent memory (using `kmalloc` and `dma_alloc_noncoherent`) for testing purposes (just in order to see if this accelerates the memory access), but in these cases the amount of memory that I cann allocate is very limited (e.g., 4MB for `kmalloc`), which is smaller than the amount of memory that I'm going to transfer in a single DMA access.

So I am not sure what are possible alternatives that might result in a higher performance.

- Is there a possibility to copy data to this region that is faster than `memcpy`?
- Is it possible to allocate larger cached memory regions? Using `dma_alloc_coherent` I can allocate up to 64 MB - why is this so much larger than the memory that can be allocated using `kmalloc`?
- What are alternative approaches?

Currently, the transfer of data to the mmaped region is the bottleneck in my application.

Best regards,
Apo

Answer (score 1):

What architecture are you using? If you are using AMRv7 dma_alloc_coherent allocates uncached memory and this is ultimate performance hit.

Comment: I already use ´dma_alloc_coherent´, but unfortunately the transfer from the "normal" memory to the uncached is very slow.